# I want to loop timestamp in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

i have a array like this

```
var thisArray = [{lat : -123123,
                  lng : 123123123,
                  time : 1494976756},
                 {lat : -123123,
                  lng : 1233,
                  time : 1495235956
                 }]
```

I want to loop it in each days, can someone help me, in output process i want like this :

```
var tempThisArray = [];
tempThisArray.push({1494976756 : {lat : -123123 ,long: 123123123}});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't write very much, but I think this is what you're looking for...

You actually don't really need jQuery, you could use an [Array forEach](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forEach.asp), which works in IE9+. You may have been having issues with assigning the object key directly in the array.push. If you want to assign the object key from a variable, you'll need to define the object first, before you push it to the array.

```
var tempThisArray = [];
var thisArray = [
  {
    'lat': -123123,
    'lng': 123123123,
    'time': 1494976756
  },
  {
    'lat': -123123,
    'lng': 1233,
    'time': 1495235956
  }
];
var tempObj = {};

thisArray.forEach(function(item, index){
  tempObj = {};
  tempObj[item['time']] = {
    'lat': item['lat'], 
    'long': item['lng']
  };

  tempThisArray.push(tempObj);
});

console.log(tempThisArray);
```

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rn709ks2/1/